# Why This Date Function Only Works Until 30 December 2016?

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {

    $monthNum  = $i;
    $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));

    $date_established = strtotime($monthName);
    $date_established = strtotime('first day of this month', $date_established);
    $date_established = date('Y-m-d', $date_established);
    $date_established_end = date("Y-m-t", strtotime($date_established));

    echo $i .'::'. $monthName . '::' . $date_established . '::' . $date_established_end . '<br>';

}
```

and so far, it produces :

```
1::January::2016-01-01::2016-01-31
2::February::2016-02-01::2016-02-28
3::March::2016-03-01::2016-03-31
4::April::2016-04-01::2016-04-30
5::May::2016-05-01::2016-05-31
6::June::2016-06-01::2016-06-30
7::July::2016-07-01::2016-07-31
8::August::2016-08-01::2016-08-31
9::September::2016-09-01::2016-09-30
10::October::2016-10-01::2016-10-31
11::November::2016-11-01::2016-11-30
12::December::2016-12-01::2016-12-31
```

but today (31 December 2016), all messed up like this :

```
1::January::2016-01-01::2016-01-31
2::February::2016-03-01::2016-03-31 
3::March::2016-03-01::2016-03-31 << duplicate
4::April::2016-05-01::2016-05-31
5::May::2016-05-01::2016-05-31 << duplicate
6::June::2016-07-01::2016-07-31
7::July::2016-07-01::2016-07-31 << duplicate
8::August::2016-08-01::2016-08-31
9::September::2016-10-01::2016-10-31
10::October::2016-10-01::2016-10-31 << duplicate
11::November::2016-12-01::2016-12-31
12::December::2016-12-01::2016-12-31 << duplicate
```

what's wrong with 31 December 2016? why my code messed up? thank you.

Comment: FWIW, 2016 is both a leap year, and a year with a leap second.

Comment: Notice that all the wrong dates are in months that have fewer than 31 days. November 31 is actually December 1.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error unless I change `10` to `31` in the `$monthName` assignment.

Comment: In your real code, are you using the current day of the month instead of hard-coding the day as in your question?

Comment: @Barmar : that's my real code. I'm not changing anything. Maybe, your current timezone still in 30 Dec. I'm 1:28 AM here. 31 Dec. That's why I have that error. And you haven't. try to change your timezone to Asia/Jakarta. You'll get result as I have.

Comment: I get that bad output with PHP 7.0.14, timezone America/Vancouver.

Comment: @miken32 : I'm using PHP 5.5 and my timezone is Asia/Jakarta

Comment: OK, with `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta")` I did reproduce it.

Comment: @Barmar : hmmm.... that's odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code fails along these lines:

```
$february = strtotime('February');
echo date(DATE_ISO8601, $february);
```

which *today, December 30, 2016* outputs:

```
2016-03-01T00:00:00+0000
```

Hmmm... why is PHP saying that "February" is "2016-03-01"? Well, it has to do with how PHP fills in the gaps for missing information: **in the absence of explicitly given absolute time values, PHP uses the current date and time's values.**

Thus, since it's December 30 at 13:29 Eastern, the following are semantically equivalent:

```
strtotime('February');                       // you asked for
strtotime('February 30, 2016 13:29:47 EST'); // PHP interprets as
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ filled in from current time
```

Clearly that latter, interpretted date is bogus. PHP (via the underlying library, actually) shifts the interpretted date using the logic that Feb 30 = Feb 29 + 1 day = Mar 1. (Worse, in a non-leap year like 2017, PHP would calculate Feb 30 = Feb 28 + 2 days = Mar 2, and the output would be "2017-03-02T00:00:00+0000"!)

So, what you need to do, under these circumstances, is be explicit when you're asking PHP for date conversion. That means instead of asking for `strtotime('February');` you ask for:

```
$year = date('Y');
$date_established = strtotime("$monthName 1, $year");
```

(or equivalent. The point being: don't let PHP fill in the missing information with the current date's values.)

Aside: These bugs are particularly hard to track down, because the code "works" when the *current* day of the month is less than the number of days in the month asked for. In my experience, it's best to avoid `strtotime` unless you absolutely need, and when you do absolutely need it, you give it as much explicit information as possible.

Comment: You beat me to this. Perhaps a better option is to use `mktime()` to make `$date_established`, instead of `strtotime()`.

Comment: @bishop : thank you for your answer, bro. now I really understand what's the problem. you save me, bro. thank you.

Comment: @RobertHanson You're welcome! These are annoying bugs. (And, as always, green check mark appreciated. :)

Comment: @RobertHanson Thanks, you too! (Maybe *resolve* to avoid `strtotime`, haha!)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this is happening, but it's easy enough to work around:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {

    $monthNum  = sprintf("%02d", $i);
    $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));

    $date_established = date("Y-$monthNum-01");
    $date_established_end = date("Y-m-t", strtotime($date_established));

    echo "$i :: $monthName :: $date_established :: $date_established_end <br>\n";

}
```

You always know that the first of the month is going to be "01" so just specify it directly.

Edit: clearly someone else knows why it's happening!